# Sqlite: is possible to create trigger with random name (or no name)?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I need to create trigger dynamically and don't need drop them in future.
So, I need a code to do this.

Likely

```
CREATE TRIGGER random() BEFORE INSERT... (with random name)
```

Or

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT... (without name)
```

Can I do this in sqlite shell?
I know, it's bad practise, but it's experiment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), `trigger-name` is an atomic syntactical unit (it can be seen from it from being lowercase, in a rounded-cornered rectangle), in the sense it cannot be constructed by evaluating complex expressions. You are only allowed to enter a literal there (same with `table-name` and `index-name` by the way, see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)).

What you can do instead is dynamically constructing the whole query string, **before** passing it to SQLite. E.g. if you are interacting with SQLite through Python, then you can write something like:

```
tableName = "someRandomString" 
db.execute("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (A INT, B TEXT)")
```

Or if you are using the Windows command prompt:

```
set tableName=someRandomString
sqlite3.exe test.sqlite "CREATE TABLE %tableName% (A INT, B TEXT)"
```

I know you were asking about triggers, not tables but it's basically the same thing from your question's perspective, and the table creation syntax is shorter.